# Set Style Setter value from code-behind at runtime

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, styling

In silverlight, there is a known textbox caret bug that is discussed here: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/165276/423268.aspx

As a workaround, an attached behaviour is used that allows to specify the color for TextBox caret explicitly.

Therefore I have the following setter in my TextBox style:

```
<Style x:Key="NameEditStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Utilities:FixCaretBrushBehavior.CaretBrush" Value="White" />
```

My application is running on Windows Phone, where there can be both White and Black backgrounds for the TextBoxes. I need to conditionally modify whether the caret will appear White to Black. (which is equivalent to setting a `Value` of the property).

How can I conditionally change this particular property in a style setter from code?

I have tried giving a property an x:Name and trying to reference it in code-behind, but the property is always `null`, so I can't adjust it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in WPF/SL/WP7 to change a style after it is loaded because the [Style.IsSealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.issealed%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) will be true. 
What you can do is to create new style based on the old one and change the TextBoxes style to the new style:

```
<Style x:Key="NameEditStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Utilities:FixCaretBrushBehavior.CaretBrush" Value="White" />
    ...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="BlackNameEditStyle" TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource NameEditStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Utilities:FixCaretBrushBehavior.CaretBrush" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

Alternatively you can also create this new style during runtime as described here in the [article](http://www.silverlightnext.com/2010/05/silverlight-4-modify-style-runtime.html).