# Getting a particular setter of a style object

Tags: wpf, silverlight, styles, code-behind, setter

I was wondering how to **retrieve a particular setter** from a style object in code-behind in silverlight.

I have a style S which is correctly loaded and applied to some object. Then **during runtime i want to alter one particular setter of this style** say its Background setter (Of course what i want is to alter the value of one particular setter).

To do so i looked at the Setters **collection** which is of type **SetterBaseCollection** and contains all setters of this style. So far so good. This collection seems to include all setters as they are defined in XAML but how to do i get access to them ?

When i iterate over this collection i am dealing with objects of type "Setter". But I don't know how to pick the one which contains the "Background" property.

```
// this works totally fine; the variable myStyle is getting the correct Style
myStyle = this.Resources["myStyle"] as Style;

// the myStyle.Setters collection seems to contain all setters of the style
foreach (Setter s in myStyle.Setters) {

   // so now what to do to get the setter that sets the Background property of my style ??

  // my naive approach did not work:
  if (s.Property.ToString().equals("Background")) {

      // do something
  }
}
```

(The Setter objects does have a Name attribute, which in fact is exactly what I want to accomplish a comparison with the string "Background" - and debugging offered that this attribute truly contains the string "Background". ... But it's a non-public attribute!

It would be **great** if anyone would have any suggestions **:)**

*p.s. My local time is 03:00 AM so i am a bit tired and overworked - so please ask me to clarify my issue again in case you have troubles guessing what i need ;)*

Comment: H.B in post below is absolutely right. `Style.IsSealed` property is true and you can not change it an runtime.    [Set Style Setter value from code-behind at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593580/set-style-setter-value-from-code-behind-at-runtime).   [Change a window style at runtime worked on VS2008, doesn't work on VS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428856/change-a-window-style-at-runtime-worked-on-vs2008-doesnt-work-on-vs2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setters in a style get sealed anyway (probably along with the containing collection once the style is in use) so you cannot modify it, styles are meant to be persistent. I would recommend you swap out the whole style with a new one or try to approach this differently.

Comment: Setters are getting sealed ? - What an useless ideas ;) no i am just kidding :) Thank you very much for your answer - I really wasn't aware of that fact ... I will have to do a different approach without altering the style once it is initialized.

Answer (score 2):

```
var prop = ((Setter)setter).Property;
if (prop.Name.Equals("Background")
{
   //do smth
}
```